# Bot Auto Can't Click Circle Because of Overlay

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, bots, microsoft-edge

#I can't click the circles

[image]

And my code:

```
num_seats = 2

for i in range(num_seats):
    seat = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "circle.seat:not(.booked)"))
    )
    # In ghế trống
    seat_id = seat.get_attribute("id")
    print("Ghế trống - ID:", seat_id)
    # Click vào ghế trống
    if not seat.get_attribute("selected") or seat.get_attribute("selected") == "false":
        seat.click()
        print("Đã Click")
```

and my error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException

I tried changing browser and using JavaScript, ActionChains but still not working

Comment: It is difficult to analyze code from an image, but the screenshot is helpful as well. Can you [edit] your question to include the relevant HTML, including any ancestor nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Remove seat.click() and replace it with my code:

```
seat_click = driver.find_element(By.ID, seat_id)
seat_click.click()
```

In case this does Not work try on of these:

1. Click on the first child of the element you are trying to click
2. Click on the first parent of the element you are trying to click